# calculating ratios with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigdata, hiveql

I am using Hiveql query to pre-proceed some raw data. In this scenario, I have a table called cloth, and I have 3 kinds of cloth with color red, blue and green. Now the question is how to calculate the ratio of each color using query?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have table named `cloth` with 3 kinds of `cloth` and 3 `color`.
So assuming fields name `cloth` and `color`.

```
select cloth, avg(Case when color='red' then 1 else 0 end)/ Count(*) * 1.0 As redratio, avg(Case when color='blue' then 1 else 0 end)/ Count(*) * 1.0 As blueratio, avg(Case when color='green' then 1 else 0 end)/ Count(*) * 1.0 As greenratio
from cloth group by cloth
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 select
 1.0 * sum(color='red')/count(*) as redRatio,
 1.0 * sum(color='green')/count(*) as greenRatio,
 1.0 * sum(color='blue')/count(*) as blueRatio
 from cloth
```